# Network Topology Discovery – Windows 7 Via GPO

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, group-policy

I wish to enable Network Discovery on my network (For various reasons) I need to apply this via GPO due to the nature of our setup. This is on a  Windows 2008 R2 Domain with Windows 7/XP Clients.

I have tried to enable this in the GPO and it shows the below;

```
> Network/Link-Layer Topology Discovery Policy  Setting Comment Turn on
> Mapper I/O (LLTDIO) driver Enabled     Allow operation while in
> domain    Enabled Allow operation while in public network Disabled
> Prohibit operation while in private network   Disabled
> 
> Policy    Setting Comment Turn on Responder (RSPNDR) driver Enabled   
> Allow operation while in domain   Enabled Allow operation while in
> public network    Disabled Prohibit operation while in private
> network   Disabled
```

But when logging onto the clients this isn’t applying. I have Run RSOP and the output isn’t showing that this has applied as well. Any comments would be appreciated

Comment: Have you allowed enough time to pass for group policy to refresh or have you forced a refresh using `gpupdate /force`?

Comment: I have run Gpupdate /force and allow it to do the logoff. But this still hasnt applied the Policy. Also I have done a reboot of the machine I am using to test. Other parts of the GPO that i have just added in are applying fine.

Comment: Looks like your settings should work.  Appears from your question that the clients just aren't receiving the GPO.  Can you run a GP Result within GPMC?  The summary tab should show you the disposition of the GPO (if it was applied/denied and why)...

Comment: Ive just looked at this http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=21895 And it says it for WinXp/Server2003 (Tryied it but wont install) Any Suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

What feature are you trying to enable with "Network Topology Discovery"?

This technology allows you to draw a graph of the network, but the button to show the network graph is only visible on `Private` networks, not `Domain`. I think it is intended for domestic/SMB usage, rather than enterprise, hence why it is hidden on domains (which can be quite a bit larger and discovery could take an extremely long time).

If you are trying to make it so that you can see other PCs in the "Network neighborhood" this is not the right setting.